# Only properties should be deleted

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm getting this error with JSLint: **Only properties should be deleted**

Why doesn't it like this?  The variable I am attempting to delete is very large, so I was hoping to get a jump on the garbage collection.  Is this not ok?

Comment: You cannot delete variables, only object properties. So even if `var a = 5; delete a;` does not throw an error (it actually does in *strict mode*), it does not do anything either (`delete a;` will return `false`). So: It's valid code, but it does not do what you want, so it is just confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling No, that's not the fact. Actually you can delete variables by delete operator. You can write and run a test code.
`var a=11; alert(delete a); alert(typeof a);`
will alert true and "undefined".

Comment: @cuixiping Felix Kling is right. You cannot delete (local) variables using `delete`. Global variables are different because they are actually properties attached to the `window` object.

Comment: Oh, I agree that I made a mistake. Yes, you're right. Variables in function cannot be delete. You can set it to undefined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`delete` is meant to delete properties on an object, not regular variables (properties on a VariableObject).

Instead, you could set all references to the value as `null`. JavaScript's GC will clean it up when it feels it needs to.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to get rid of the jslint warning, you can try this:

```
var myHugeVariable = ...;

// do stuff with huge variable

delete window.myHugeVariable;
```

This should work since all global variables are actually properties of the global object.

Comment: What about local variables? ;)

Comment: @FelixKling good question. i am 70% sure that all variables declared anywhere must be properties of some object, it's just a matter of figuring out what object they exist under.

Comment: @jbabey Normal variables are properties of a VariableObject of an execution context, which does not have a public interface in the JavaScript API. As far as my memory of the spec goes, at least :P

Comment: @alex i have never heard of this VariableObject before, do you have any good links that explain how it works?

Comment: @jbabey [This link](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-2-variable-object/) looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, it's unnecessary to release variables. The javascript engine does that things automatically.

Or, you can let the variable equal to undefined, so you can pass jslint check.

```
var a=11;
a = undefined;
```

It's not recommended.